# change axis formatt to integers

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have data in this format:

```
 Temperatura   Res Germanio 
2  285.47008547   172.283272283
3  285.592185592  171.916971917
4  285.836385836  171.672771673
5  286.324786325  171.428571429
6  286.446886447  171.062271062....
```

i am plotting with matplotlib,

```
plt.plot(df['Temperatura'], df['Res Germanio'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(100, 300, step=50))
plt.yticks(np.arange(100, 200, step=20))
plt.show()
```

I've tried the fix suggested by the other post too:

```
plt.plot(df['Temperatura'], df['Res Germanio'])
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(df['Temperatura']), max(df['Temperatura'])+1, 10.0))
plt.show()
plt.show()
```

this also doesn't work.

howver I am unable to get reasonable axis:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koK1t.png)

what code should I use ?

Comment: Please be more specific as to your problem. Are you asking for the x-axis labels to not overlap, or for the labels to be only at integers, or something else?

Comment: I want my xaxis labels to not overlap and be integers